# getInetAddress() returns 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a Android app that connects to a server using Object streams all wrote in Java. It used to work fine and all of a sudden with nothing being changed the connection keeps timing out. I added a line to print the address the socket is connected to on the server side using socket. getInetAddress() but simply returns 0.0.0.0. Does anyone have any ideas why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the wildcard address ... it means your server is binding to all IPs on the machine. (And that's perfectly normal)

Comment: Actually, 0.0.0.0 means "this host on this network". https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1700  That happens to also be used by socket layers as a shorthand for "all addresses on this machine". (Goes all the way back to Berkeley sockets in C. INADDR_ANY was defined to be an unsigned long 0x00000000.)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was using `INADDR_ANY` in `C` on the linux 1.0 kernel before that RFC was published. ;) Sorry if I don't choose to be super-technical in answering basic questions these days; I think "wildcard" is a fairly accurate layman's term to describe it. Thanks for reminding me I'm from "way back" though :-p

Comment: Ok thats good to know. Would you know why my connection would be timing out? It is running on my universities server and has been working for 3 months fine and then stopped. It's not that there are too many connections because it has only been me connecting to it and I don't leave it running while I'm not using it. I'm very confused to what could have changed. I tested the code on another machine and it works perfectly fine and I tried different ports and nothing happens.

Comment: @user1160163 - a client timing out is unrelated. If the server is up and you can connect to it from the local machine you have a network/firewall issue that's preventing you from connecting.

Comment: The server admins got back to me. They had blocked ports. But thanks for the help