# ServerSocket IP assignment in Java

Tags: java, serversocket

When you create a ServerSocket in Java as such:

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8888);
```

Is the host IP automatically bound to it.  Or is it necessary to use the three parameter constructor and specify the IP?

Comment: I neutralized the question score because it doesn't really deserve a negative. But FYI if you do read through the javadoc you can get an idea that it does bind to the local address by default. And if this was an argument you can sure shut the other people up faster by simply whipping up a demo in your IDE faster than you'd get an useful answer here...

Comment: I did.  However, when I bound it explicitly the getInetAddress() method returned the local address, and when I didn't it returned a 0.0.0.0. So the argument continued.  Found a good answer here, thought: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9778260/844620

Comment: @webhound - `0.0.0.0` is the wildcard address.  It means "any address".  That should have ended the argument, one way or another.

Comment: For reference - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Its no necessary, maybe if the PC has more than one network card.
[ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29)

Comment: It's not necessary at all unless (a) the PC has more than one network *address,* **and** (b) you want the ServerSocket to receive from only one of those addresses.